# How to access remote SIP phone book through Jami?

Tags: software-recommendation, phone, voip, sip, address-book

I have a Snom phone connecting to a commercial SIP provider that my company is using. It has a phone book function where all my co-workers are available automatically.

I wanted to switch to a soft IP phone on Ubuntu. I installed Jami and entered my credentials of the SIP account. It says I'm connected. But nowhere can I find the phone book of my co-workers, like the Snom hardware phone was displaying automatcially (must be fetched automatically from the SIP server, because it even works after a full reset of the Snom and new co-workers appear automatically).

Without this phone book the soft IP phone / Jami is useless, because I can not remember hundreds of number-name pairs.

Is this a limitation of Jami (what better software is there?) or do I need special configuration to access the phone book that should be auto-provided by the SIP provider?